# Why article is not split into two columns

Tags: multicol

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scimisc-cv}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\twocolumn
\begin{multicols}
\item \textbf {AAAA}
\item \textbf {AAAAA}
\item \textbf {AAAA}
\item \textbf {AAAA}
\item \textbf {AAA}
\end{multicols}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to split this column in two-columns equally but why isn’t two-column working?

Comment: Welcome to tex.stackexchange. Please try and use a guide to provide a working MWE, e.g. [this question]{https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `enumitem`+ (`multicol` used by the user @Kubo) packages you can split equally! with the two options `noitemsep`, `nolistsep`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\item \textbf {AAAA}
\item \textbf {AAAAA}
\item \textbf {AAAA}
\item \textbf {AAAA}
\item \textbf {AAA}
\end{multicols}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No is doesnt work!

Comment: Why? There is a screenshot. ..I have not put the package `scimisc-cv` because I have not `.sty` of this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to load the [`multicol`](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol?lang=de)-package and add a parameter so the environment knows it is supposed to use two columns. You don’t need `\twocolumn` if you use the `\multicols`-environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\item \textbf {AAAA}
\item \textbf {AAAAA}
\item \textbf {AAAA}
\item \textbf {AAAA}
\item \textbf {AAA}
\end{multicols}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that but it's not split equally! The last side there is a blank!

Comment: Use Sebastianos additional parameters `noitemsep` and `nolistsep` with `enumitem`. I was was quicker, but his answer is better.

Comment: @Kubo You has been very good....and I have upvoted you.